# Undirected Graphs with weighted node potentials in R

Tags: r

I am brand new to R and I am using library (grid), (graph), (Rgraphviz) and gRbase to try make a Undirected Graph for calculating marginal probability of each node and running the sum product algorithm on all the nodes.

This is my graph:
g1 <- ug(~1:2 + 1:3 + 2:4 + 2:5) and it looks pretty when I plot(g1). The problem is I have no idea how to input the node potentials and pairwise potentials onto the graph in R nor how to code up the sum-product algorithm in R. Any help or a reference to help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you can add potentials in `gRbase`, but you can in `gRain`, also, `gRain` uses the junction tree algorithm for inference

Comment: [`gRain`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRain/index.html) also has a vignette, and there are one or two other guides floating about the www by the package author.